# Replace href with unique string and re add later

Tags: javascript, php

I have a situation where I need to strip out all HTML from a string and then re add it later with JavaScript.

For example

```
<h3>header</h3><br>Lorem Ipsum
```

Becomes

```
###H3###header###/H3######BR###Lorem Ipsum
```

I then use a JavaScript function to look for these ### tags and replace them with proper HTML

I'm stuck at how to do this with a href though.  Does anybody have any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Post example of data where you stuck, href.